# Encode cyrillic UTF-8 to Unicode symbols

Tags: php, postgresql, unicode

In a project's code there's this part:

```
$companies = $db->fetchAll("SELECT id FROM companies where contact_person like '%num%\"". $num. "\"%'");
```

For example, $num = 'ЦВ123456' (ЦВ - cyrillic symbols). But in the db ЦВ is stored in unicode - `\u0426\u0412`. So there are no hits. So how can I convert $num to unicode so the query becomes `...contact_person like '\u0426\u0412123456` ?

Comment: `json_encode('ЦВ123456')` gets you `"\u0426\u0412123456"`. If you can't use it with the double quotes around it, use `trim` to remove them.

Answer (score 1):

you can use php build in mb-convert encoding,
convert your $string to the encoding used in the database , and query with the encoded value

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php

something like this

```
$string = "ЦВ123456";
$unicode = mb_convert_encoding($string,  "utf-8", "unicode");
```